# Why does C# say the x variable doesn't exist in the current context? The x variable in my if statement is getting the error

Tags: c#, for-loop, visual-studio-code, break

Beginner here, and I am going crazy trying to figure out why the x in my if statement isn't being recognized. The following error shows: The name 'x' does not exist in the current context.

```
for (int x = 15; x < 30; x++);
{
    if (x == 20)
    {
        break; 
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

I copied (not copy paste, but typed it key for key) this example from the W3 website but with different values and identifiers for my variables, which makes me assume the website I'm learning from is outdated. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Remove the `;` before the first `{`

Comment: It is convention to use `i` as a `for` loop counter unless you want to use a more descriptive name for something specific. `x` doesn't really qualify, so you ought to stick with `i`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a spurious semicolon at the end of the first line. That code is actually equivalent to this:

```cs
for (int x = 15; x < 30; x++)
{
}
{
    if (x == 20)
    {
        break; 
    } 
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Hopefully that makes it clear why the `x` variable is out of scope for the second block.